# Find the positive integers $x^3+y^3=3z^3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

By [Fermat Last theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), I don't know if that's been discussed.

Find all positive integers $x,y,z$ such
$$x^3+y^3=3z^3$$

Comment: This is a genus-$1$ curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ with a rational point $[1:-1:0]$ isomorphic over $\mathbf{Q}$ to the elliptic curve $E: y^2-y=x^3-\frac{1}{3}$ with algebraic rank $0$ (according to MAGMA).

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D3z%5E3%24&p=1) I found this post on Mathematics about this equation: [Three variable, third degree Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14721).

Comment: For a generalisation: *Which primes are sums of two cubes?* https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/mpim/95-61/fulltext.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This is proved in Hardy and Wright, (An introduction to the theory of numbers),
Theorem 232. (After proving first the classical $x^3+y^3=z^3$, the notation and methods are ready, to prove this case in a quite similar way.)